# How to Convert a comma separated log/ csv file to excel .xlsx file

Tags: perl, unix

Perl/ Unix script to convert a comma separated log file to excel(XLSX) file

log file format

```
string1,string2,string3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Import the csv file with your excel program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need a script here! You can simply follow steps:

1. Change extension of *log* file to `.csv`
2. Open `.csv` file in *Microsoft Excel* and
3. Save file as `.xlsx`

Comment: log file has comma if we open in excel all column will be open in one column of excel

Comment: Look for the "text to columns" button, depending on your excel version you might find it under "data" tab

Comment: nope. consider changing extension of log file first to `.csv` then excel will take care rest all for you

Comment: Thats not an issue, i need to email excel, and it should be automated

Comment: @JerseyIT You can mail `.csv` and recipient can view it in Excel. I am not telling that what you are looking for is not possible. But it doesn't make any sense to me atleast. If you still want to do it check [Excel-Writer-XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.05/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm)

Comment: @JerseyIT There are may such modules available in `CPAN` for handling Excel data in `Perl`. Google should help you. You can try and come back with a question where you can't make it work.

Comment: I have a bunch of CSV files that must be imported into a file management system.  The file management system can only handle XLSX spreadsheet.  Yes, I can open each one and convert them manually, but that can take the better part of a day.